# Generating one-time URLs (to email) with PHP

Tags: php, html, email, url, hyperlink

My reason for this is generating one-time URLs, and send this link to a person that is submitted to the databse, via e-mail. This one-time link is for a recruitment test (that by the way should only be seen by the person who recieved the email). 
I'm not quite sure how to proceed, any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: did you try something, please read how to ask questions on stackoverflow

Comment: see this link.... https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiiq7Hb247PAhUI42MKHVH5AJ0QFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sitepoint.com%2Fgenerating-one-time-use-urls%2F&usg=AFQjCNEH3b3wF5AJoWUl6xScjwp6TtSJ9w&sig2=7g8BjXoeb7zB4i_FrKHetgphp

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below to generate a one-time URL with random hash. You can use it to identify the user that clicked the link in the email against your candidate database.

```
<?php

// Generate a random hash
$bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16, $cstrong);
$hex   = bin2hex($bytes);

// Add the hash to your verification script URL
$url = "http://www.yourwebsite.com/verify.php?hash=" . $hex;

// Print the verification link
print("<a href='" . $url . "'>Your verification link</a>");

?>
```

Comment: https://www.phpclasses.org/package/9634-PHP-Generate-URL-that-only-works-one-time-for-the-user.html you can check this out. you will need to make changes for specific use case. hope it helps.